# Store regex matches into variables

Tags: r, regex

How can I use regex to store the matches into variables in R?

For instance my strings:

```
"1 win & 1 nomination." 
"1 win & 1 nominations."
"1 wins & 1 nomination."
"1 win"
"21 nominations."
```

I want to store the number of wins and nominations for later use

expected output for the sample about would be:

```
Wins  nominations
 1    1
 1    1
 1    1
 1    0
 0    21
```

regex that I have:

`\d+\s+win.*\d+\s+nomination.*`

Comment: Why not extract the matches in 2 steps? `Wins <- stringr::str_extract(x, "\\d+(?=\\s+win)")` and `nominations <- stringr::str_extract(x, "\\d+(?=\\s+nomination)")`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ill take it! I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may extract the numbers before `wins` with `\d+(?=\s+win)` regex and those before `nominations` with `\\d+(?=\\s+nomination)` using `stringr::str_extract`:

```
library(stringr)
Wins <- str_extract(x, "\\d+(?=\\s+win)")
Wins[is.na(Wins)] <- 0
nominations <- str_extract(x, "\\d+(?=\\s+nomination)")
nominations[is.na(nominations)] <- 0
df <- data.frame(Wins, nominations)
df
  Wins nominations
1    1           1
2    1           1
3    1           1
4    1           0
5    0          21
```

If there can be no whitespace between the number and the word, use `\s*` instead of `\s+`.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to your regex:

> (\d+)\s+win.*(\d+)\s+nomination.*

This helps you capture the two numbers on each line,

You can then print them with:

> \1\t\2

Where \1 refers to the number of wins,
\t is a tab character,
\2 the nominations number